# searching multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have array like this

```
$lists=
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [item] => Global ISDN Switchtype = primary-net5 ) 
[1] => Array ( [item] => ISDN Serial0/0/0:15 interface ) 
[2] => Array ( [item] => dsl 0, interface ISDN Switchtype = primary-net5 ) 
[3] => Array ( [item] => Layer 1 Status: ) 
[4] => Array ( [item] => ACTIVE ) 
[5] => Array ( [item] => Layer 2 Status: ) 
[6] => Array ( [item] => TEI = 0, Ces = 1, SAPI = 0, State = MULTIPLE_FRAME_ESTABLISHED ) 
[7] => Array ( [item] => Layer 3 Status: ) 
[8] => Array ( [item] => 13 Active Layer 3 Call(s) ) 
[9] => Array ( [item] => CCB:callid=122A, sapi=0, ces=0, B-chan=22, calltype=VOICE ) 
[10] => Array ( [item] => CCB:callid=126D, sapi=0, ces=0, B-chan=17, calltype=VOICE ) 
[11] => Array ( [item] => CCB:callid=1279, sapi=0, ces=0, B-chan=24, calltype=VOICE ) 
[12] => Array ( [item] => CCB:callid=12C5, sapi=0, ces=0, B-chan=1, calltype=VOICE ) 
[13] => Array ( [item] => CCB:callid=12D5, sapi=0, ces=0, B-chan=5, calltype=VOICE ) 
[14] => Array ( [item] => ACTIVE ) 
)
```

how i can get retirn value index of ACTIVE?

search_array($lists,'ACTIVE'); and the results is 4,14

Many Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result=array();
$count=count($lists);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
  if($lists[$i]['item']=='ACTIVE') {
    $result[]=$i;
  }
}
$result=implode(",",$result);
```

Answer (score 1):

On PHP 5.5, and as long as you array is indexed with consecutive integer keys, you can use the convenient

```
$indexes = array_keys(array_column($lists, 'item'), 'ACTIVE');
```

Alternatively you can use `array_walk`. The solution is a little more verbose, but it has many advantages:

- Works in PHP >= 5.3
- Works no matter what the keys in `$lists` are
- Uses less memory (only really important if your array is very large)

The code:

```
$indexes = array();
array_walk($lists, function($i, $key) use (&$indexes) {
               if ($i['item'] == 'ACTIVE') $indexes[] = $key;
           });
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/gLetMp)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
// $lists is your array

function q($item, $key) {
  if ($item == 'ACTIVE')
    echo $key.", ";
}

array_walk_recursive($lists, 'q');
?>
```